# Lista encadeada - Erro ao inserir elemento - [warning] passing argument 1 of 'strncpy' makes pointer from integer without a cast

Tags: c, lista, estrutura-de-dados

Boa tarde, poderiam por gentileza me ajudar no meu projeto?
Tenho que criar uma lista encadeada que grave dados de horário de ônibus, porem quando tento executar, logo apos inserir os dados do horário aparece um erro, conforme abaixo:
[image: Print erro]

Quando tento compilar aparece algumas advertências que não consegui intender, imagem abaixo:
Em laranja - [Warning] passing argument 1 of 'strlen' makes pointer from integer without a cast

[image: Print erro 2]

Vou colocar o código abaixo:

main.c

```
//Bibliotecas utilizadas
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "lista.h"

 //Inicializando os dados da lista
Dados *principal = NULL;

//---------------------------------
//     Função Principal
//---------------------------------

int main(void) {
    char escolha;
    int chave=0;
    //Laço que irá mostrar o menu esperando uma opção (char)
    do {
        //Limpando a tela, e mostrando o menu lembrando que primeiramente, os itens estão bloqueados até que seja criada uma lista vazia
        LIMPA_TELA;
        fprintf(stdout, "\n\t\tHorario de onibus\n\n");
        fprintf(stdout, "Escolha uma opcao: \n");
        fprintf(stdout, "1 - Criar lista vazia\n");
        if(chave==1){
            fprintf(stdout, "2 - Inserir no Inicio de uma lista\n");
            fprintf(stdout, "3 - Inserir no Fim de uma lista\n");
        }
        fprintf(stdout, "4 - Lista Vazia...\n");
        if(chave==1){
            fprintf(stdout, "5 - Exibir dados do primeiro elemento\n");
            fprintf(stdout, "6 - Exibir dados do ultimo elemento\n");
            fprintf(stdout, "7 - Exibir todos os valores da Lista\n");
            fprintf(stdout, "8 - Exibir o tamanho da Lista\n");
            fprintf(stdout, "9 - Eliminar primeiro elemento\n");
            fprintf(stdout, "a - Eliminar último elemento\n");
            fprintf(stdout, "b - Eliminar elemento buscado\n");
            fprintf(stdout, "c - Busca Dados\n");
        }
        fprintf(stdout, "d - Sair\n\n");
        fprintf(stdout, "Resposta: ");
        scanf("%c", &escolha);
        //Se a chave for diferente de zero, porém a escolha for diferente de 1, 4 e d, a escolha será z (opção inválida)
        if((chave==0)&&((escolha!='1')&&(escolha!='d')&&(escolha!='4')))
            escolha='z';

        switch(escolha) {
            //Criando lista vazia
            case '1':
                chave=1;
                criavazia(); 
                break;
            //Inserindo no início
            case '2':
                insereinicio();
                break;                
            //Inserindo no final
            case '3':
                //Se a lista não estiver vazia
                if(principal!=NULL){
                    inserefim();
                }
                //senão inclui no inicio
                else{
                    insereinicio();
                }
                break;
            //Checando se a lista está vazia
            case '4':
                listavazia();
                break;
            //Mostrando Primeiro elemento
            case '5':
                prielemento();
                break;
            //Mostrando Último elemento
            case '6':
                ultelemento();
                break;
            //Exibindo todos elementos
            case '7':
                exibe();
                break;
            //Exibindo tamanho da lista
            case '8':
                exibetam();
                break;
            //Deleta primeiro elementos
            case '9':
                deletapri();
                break;                
            //Deleta último elemento
            case 'a':
                deleta();
                break;
            //Deleta elemento buscado
            case 'b':
                delbusca();
                break;                
            //Buscando elementos
            case 'c':
                busca();
                break;
            //Saindo e finalizando o programa
            case 'd':
                fprintf(stderr,"Obrigado por utilizar esse programa!\n");
                fprintf(stderr,"------>Terminal de Informação<------\n\n");
                ESPERA;
                //exit(0);
                break;
            //Se foi algum valor inválido
            default:
                fprintf(stderr,"Digite uma opcao valida (pressione -Enter- p/ continuar)!\n");
                getchar();
                break;
        }
        //Impedindo sujeira na gravação da escolha
        getchar();
    }
    while (escolha > 0); //Loop Infinito
    return 0;
}
```

lista.h

```
//Se o sistema for Windows adiciona determinada biblioteca, e definindo comandos de limpar e esperar
#ifdef WIN32
    #include <windows.h>
    #define LIMPA_TELA system("cls")
//Senão for Windows (ex.: Linux)
#else
    #include <unistd.h>
    #define LIMPA_TELA system("/usr/bin/clear")
#endif

//Máximo de bytes para uma String
#define BUFFER 64

//Espera 3 segundos
#define ESPERA sleep(3)

//Estrutura da lista que será criada
typedef struct lista {
    char *nome;
    char horario;
    float preco;
    struct lista *proximo;
} Dados;

extern Dados *principal;

//Funções para manusear os dados (irão retornar dados)
Dados *inicia_dados  (char *nome, char horario, float preco);
Dados *insere_dados  (Dados *dados, char *nome, char horario, float preco);
Dados *delbusca_dados(Dados *dados, char *chave);
Dados *deleta_dados  (Dados *dados, int nTipo);
int   checa_vazio    (Dados *dados);

//Funções para mostrar dados
void  exibe_dados    (Dados *dados);
void  exibe_tamanho  (Dados *nova);
void  busca_dados    (Dados *dados, char *chave);

//Funções do Menu
void criavazia(void);    //1
void insereinicio(void); //2
void inserefim(void);    //3
void listavazia(void);   //4
void prielemento(void);  //5
void ultelemento(void);  //6
void exibe(void);        //7
void exibetam(void);     //8
void deletapri(void);    //9
void deleta(void);       //a
void delbusca(void);     //b
void busca(void);        //c
```

lista.c

```
//Bibliotecas utilizadas
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "lista.h"

//---------------------------------
//     Opção '1'
//---------------------------------

//Criando uma lista vazia
void criavazia(void){
    char *nome;
    char horario;
    float preco;
    //Alocando dados para uma String
    nome = (char *)malloc(BUFFER);
    //Lendo String Nome
    fprintf(stdout, "\n\nDigite o Nome: \n----> ");
    scanf("%s", nome);
    fprintf(stdout, "\n");
    //Lendo String horario
    fprintf(stdout, "\n\nDigite o Horario: \n----> ");
    scanf("%s", horario);
    fprintf(stdout, "\n");
    //Lendo float preco
    fprintf(stdout, "Digite a preco: \n----> ");
    scanf("%f", &preco);
    fprintf(stdout, "\n");

    //Lançando os dados lidos na lista Principal
    free(principal);
    principal = inicia_dados(nome, horario, preco);
}

//Iniciando os dados da lista vazia
Dados *inicia_dados(char *nome, char horario, float preco) {
    Dados *novo;
    //Alocando memória para a posição atual da lista
    novo = (Dados *)malloc(sizeof(Dados));
    //Lançando os dados lidos
    novo->nome = (char *)malloc(strlen(nome)+1);
    strncpy(novo->nome, nome, strlen(nome)+1);
    strncpy(novo->horario, horario, strlen(horario)+1);
    novo->preco = preco;
    //Apontando para a próxima posição da lista
    novo->proximo = NULL;
    return novo;
}

//---------------------------------
//     Opção '2'
//---------------------------------

//Inserindo no início da lista
void insereinicio(void){
    char *nome;
    char horario;
    float preco;
    //Reservando espaço para String
    nome = (char *)malloc(BUFFER);
    //Armazenando String Nome
    fprintf(stdout, "\n\nDigite o Nome: \n----> ");
    scanf("%s", nome);
    fprintf(stdout, "\n");
    //Armazenando String Horario
    fprintf(stdout, "\n\nDigite o Horario: \n----> ");
    scanf("%s", horario);
    fprintf(stdout, "\n");
    //Armazenando int preco
    fprintf(stdout, "Digite a preco: \n----> ");
    scanf("%f", &preco);
    fprintf(stdout, "\n");
    //Lançando dados no ínicio da lista
    principal = insere_dados(principal, nome, horario, preco);
}

//Inserindo dados recebidos
Dados *insere_dados(Dados *dados, char *nome, char horario, float preco) {
    Dados *inicio;
    //Alocando memória para a posição atual
    inicio = (Dados *)malloc(sizeof(Dados));
    //Lançando os dados lidos
    inicio->nome = (char *)malloc(strlen(nome)+1);
    strncpy(inicio->nome, nome, strlen(nome)+1);
    strncpy(inicio->horario, horario, strlen(horario)+1);
    inicio->preco = preco;
    //O próximo valor aponta para a lista já existente
    inicio->proximo = dados;
    return inicio;
}

//---------------------------------
//     Opção '3'
//---------------------------------

//Inserção de dados no final de uma lista
void inserefim(void) {
    char *nome;
    char horario;
    float preco;
    //Alocação de espaço para String Nome
    nome = (char *)malloc(BUFFER);
    //Armazenando String Nome
    fprintf(stdout, "\n\nDigite o Nome: \n----> ");
    scanf("%s", nome);
    fprintf(stdout, "\n");
    //Armazenando String Horario
    fprintf(stdout, "\n\nDigite o Horario: \n----> ");
    scanf("%s", horario);
    fprintf(stdout, "\n");
    //Armazenando Float preco
    fprintf(stdout, "Digite a preco: \n----> ");
    scanf("%f", &preco);
    fprintf(stdout, "\n");
    //Criando listas auxiliares        
    Dados *final,*aux;
    //Alocando dados para a posição final da lista
    final = (Dados *)malloc(sizeof(Dados));
    //Setando os valores Nome e preco
    final->nome = (char *)malloc(strlen(nome)+1);
    strncpy(final->nome, nome, strlen(nome)+1);
    strncpy(final->horario, horario, strlen(horario)+1);
    final->preco = preco;
    //A proxima posição será Nulo
    final->proximo=NULL;
    //A lista auxiliar será igual a Principal
    aux=principal;
    //Enquanto o próximo de auxiliar não for Nulo
    while(aux->proximo!=NULL){
        aux=aux->proximo;
    }
    //O último valor, será Nulo, e depois apontando para
    //o Final
    aux->proximo=NULL;
    aux->proximo=final;
}

//---------------------------------
//     Opção '4'
//---------------------------------

//Função que testa se a lista está vazia
void listavazia(void){
    if (principal == NULL) 
        fprintf(stdout, "\n\nLista esta Vazia!\n\n ");
    else
        fprintf(stdout, "\n\nLista nao esta Vazia!\n\n ");
    getchar();
}

//---------------------------------
//     Opção '5'
//---------------------------------

//Mostrar o primeiro elemento da lista
void prielemento(void){
    fprintf(stdout, "------------------------\n");  
    fprintf(stdout, "Nome: %s\n", principal->nome);
    fprintf(stdout, "Horario: %s\n", principal->horario);
    fprintf(stdout, "preco: %d\n", principal->preco);
    fprintf(stdout, "------------------------\n");
    getchar();
}

//---------------------------------
//     Opção '6'
//---------------------------------

//Mostrando o último elemento da lista
void ultelemento(void){
    Dados *aux=principal;
    //Enquanto o próximo elemento não for NULL
    //Avance uma posição
    while(aux->proximo!=NULL){
        aux=aux->proximo;
    }
    fprintf(stdout, "------------------------\n");  
    fprintf(stdout, "Nome: %s\n", aux->nome);
    fprintf(stdout, "Horario: %s\n", aux->horario);
    fprintf(stdout, "preco: %d\n", aux->preco);
    fprintf(stdout, "------------------------\n");
    getchar();
}

//---------------------------------
//     Opção '7'
//---------------------------------

//Exibindo dados da lista
void exibe(void) {
    //Se não estiver vazio, exibe os dados
    if (!checa_vazio(principal))
        exibe_dados(principal);
}

//Exibindo todos os dados do menu
void exibe_dados(Dados *dados) {
    fprintf(stdout, "Cadastro de onibus:\n\n");
    fprintf(stdout, "------------------------\n");
    //Exibindo todos os valores da lista
    for (; dados != NULL; dados = dados->proximo) {
        fprintf(stdout, "Nome: %s\n", dados->nome);
        fprintf(stdout, "Horario: %s\n", dados->horario);
        fprintf(stdout, "preco: %d\n", dados->preco);
        fprintf(stdout, "------------------------\n");
    }
    getchar();
}

//---------------------------------
//     Opção '8'
//---------------------------------

//Exibindo o tamanho da lista
void exibetam(void){
    //Se não estiver vazio, exibe os dados
    if (!checa_vazio(principal))
        exibe_tamanho(principal);
}

//Exibindo o tamanho total (bytes) e quantpreco
void exibe_tamanho(Dados *nova){
  int aux=0, tamanho=0;
  fprintf(stdout, "\n------------------------\n");
  //Correndo todos os valores da Lista
  for (; nova != NULL; nova = nova->proximo) {
    aux++;
    tamanho+=sizeof(nova);
  }
  fprintf(stdout, "Total de Elementos: %d\nTamanho Total: %d bytes\n",aux,tamanho);
  fprintf(stdout, "------------------------\n");
  getchar();
}

//---------------------------------
//     Opção '9' e 'a'
//---------------------------------

//Deleta o Primeiro valor
void deletapri(void) {
    //Se não estiver vazio, deleta os dados
    if (!checa_vazio(principal))
        principal = deleta_dados(principal,1);
}

//Deleta o Último valor
void deleta(void) {
    //Se não estiver vazio, deleta os dados
    if (!checa_vazio(principal))
        principal = deleta_dados(principal,2);
}

//Deleta registros da lista, Tipo 1 = Inicio, Tipo 2 = Fim
Dados *deleta_dados(Dados *dados, int nTipo) {
    if(nTipo==1){
        //Apontando para a próxima posição
        Dados *novo;
        novo = dados->proximo;
        //Limpando os dados
        free(dados->nome);
        free(dados);
        fprintf(stdout, "O primeiro registro foi deletado  com sucesso.\n");
        getchar();
        return novo;
    }
    if(nTipo==2){
        Dados *novo=dados, *aux=dados;
        //Se a lista estiver no fim, exclui o que restou
        if(novo->proximo==NULL){
            free(novo);
            aux=NULL;
        }
        else{
            //Laço de repetição para chegar no fim da lista
            while(novo->proximo!=NULL){
                novo=novo->proximo;
            }
            //Preenchendo os dados da lista auxiliar
            while(aux->proximo!=novo){
                aux=aux->proximo;
            }
            //Limpando os dados e apontando para nulo
            free(novo);
            aux->proximo=NULL;
        }
        fprintf(stdout, "O ultimo registro foi deletado com sucesso.\n");
        getchar();
        return aux;
    }
}

//---------------------------------
//     Opção 'b'
//---------------------------------

//Deletando valor buscado
void delbusca(void) {
    char *chave;
    //Se não estiver vazio
    if (!checa_vazio(principal)) {
        chave = (char *)malloc(BUFFER);
        //Armazenando o valor digitado
        fprintf(stdout, "Digite o nome para buscar: \n--> ");
        scanf("%s", chave);
        //Deletando a chave buscada
        principal = delbusca_dados(principal, chave);
    }
}

//Deletando os valores buscados
Dados *delbusca_dados(Dados *dados, char *chave) {
    int achou=0,cont=0;
    Dados *juntou, *aux, *nova=dados;        

    //Correndo a lista e verificando se encontrou a string buscada, se sim, aumenta o contador e seta a variável de busca
    for (; nova != NULL; nova = nova->proximo) {
        if (strcmp(chave, nova->nome) == 0) {
            achou=1;
            cont++;
        }
    }

    //Se encontrou a busca
    if(achou==1){
        int ind=0;
        //Correndo a lista
        for(ind=0;ind<cont;ind++){
            //Se encontrou na primeira casa apaga a primeira casa
            if(strcmp(chave,dados->nome)==0){
                aux=dados;
                dados=dados->proximo;
                free(aux);
            }
            //Senão, procura até encontrar
            else{
                aux=dados;
                //Posiciona na frente do encontro para exclusão
                while(strcmp(chave,aux->nome)!=0){
                    aux=aux->proximo;
                }

                juntou=dados;
                //Enquanto o auxiliar juntou for diferente do posicionado para exclusão
                while(juntou->proximo!=aux){
                    juntou=juntou->proximo;
                }
                //Aponta para o próximo valor válido
                juntou->proximo=aux->proximo;

                free(aux);
            }
        }
        fprintf(stdout, "Excluido.\n");
    }
    else
        fprintf(stdout, "Nenhum resultado encontrado.\n");

    getchar();
    return dados;
}

//---------------------------------
//     Opção 'c'
//---------------------------------

//Função que busca os dados
void busca(void) {
    char *chave;
    //Senão estiver vazio a lista
    if (!checa_vazio(principal)) {
        chave = (char *)malloc(BUFFER);
        //Lendo o nome que será buscado
        fprintf(stdout, "Digite o nome para buscar: \n--> ");
        scanf("%s", chave);
        //chamando a função que irá procurar o nome
        busca_dados(principal, chave);
    }
}

//Percorre cada ponta da lista verificando busca
void busca_dados(Dados *dados, char *chave) {
    int achou = 0;
    fprintf(stdout, "Cadastro:\n\n");
    //Percorrendo todas as posições
    for (; dados != NULL; dados = dados->proximo) {
        //Se encontrou, mostra os dados
        if (strcmp(chave, dados->nome) == 0) {
            fprintf(stdout, "------------------------\n");
            fprintf(stdout, "Nome: %s\n", dados->nome);
            fprintf(stdout, "Horario: %s\n", dados->horario);
            fprintf(stdout, "preco: %f\n", dados->preco);
            fprintf(stdout, "------------------------\n");
            achou++;
        }
    }

    //Mostrando o resultado da busca
    if (achou == 0)
        fprintf(stdout, "Nenhum resultado encontrado.\n");
    else
        fprintf(stdout, "Foram encontrado(s) %d registro(s).\n", achou);

    getchar();
}

//---------------------------------
//     Função Auxiliar
//---------------------------------

//Função que testa se a lista esta vazia
int checa_vazio(Dados *dados) {
    //Se a lista estiver vazia
    if (dados == NULL) {
            fprintf(stdout, "Lista vazia!\n");
            getchar();
            return 1;
    } else
            return 0;
}
```

Comment: Primeiro erro que encontrei é que seu horario é um char de 1 caracter e não uma string

Comment: @AndreLacomski Esse é o erro mencionado pelo warning, que responde de forma direta à pergunta. Formalize uma resposta com isso.

Comment: Consegui pessoal foi a questão da string mesmo, muito obrigado!
@AndreLacomski e Isac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é na seguinte chamada da função 'strlen':

> strncpy(novo->horario, horario, strlen(horario)+1);

No caso, o argumento 'horário' não é do tipo esperado pela função 'strlen'. A função 'strlen' espera um ponteiro de char, 'const char *', mas você fornece um 'char'.

Para ilustrar o problema, fiz o pequeno programa abaixo. Nele você verá que na compilação pelo MinGW (usado pelo Code::Blocks) ocorrerá o mesmo 'warning'. Ao executar o programa, o primeiro 'printf' será executado com sucesso, mas o segundo (com argumento do tipo 'char') causará o mesmo erro que você está tendo.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char *s = "abc";
    printf("Tamanho de s: %d", strlen(s));

    char c = 'a';
    printf("Tamanho de c: %d", strlen(c));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Fiz como você falou e deu certo, muito obrigado mesmo!
@alandplm

Answer (score 0):

É impressão minha ou você se esqueceu de liberar a memória alocada pela lista? Embora não seja praticamente necessário, é muito oportuno.

Eu também, por praticidade, costumo utilizar uma única lista encadeada, mas do tipo `cell*`, em escopo global para trabalhar, por isso o procedimento abaixo é vazio de parâmetro. Para quem opta por fornecer o endereço de uma lista local a uma função, porém, basta realizar alguns ajustes neste algoritmo.

```
void free_llist(void)
{
    if (linked_list)
    {
        cell* aux = linked_list;

        while (linked_list)
        {
            aux = linked_list;
            linked_list = linked_list->next;
            free(aux);
            aux = (cell*) 0;
        }

        free(linked_list);
        linked_list = (cell*) 0;
    }

    return;
}
```